# Generate a list of multiples in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

If I have a list of n numbers and want to generate a new list only the numbers that are multiples of any of the other numbers in the same list.

For example, for this list: `'(2 4 5 7 10)` the result should be the list `'(4 10)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be easier if we split the problem in parts. First, let's define what it means for us to *be a multiple*, and write a procedure that implements our definition:

```
(define (is-multiple? num x)
  (and (not (= num x))
       (zero? (modulo num x))))
```

Now, let's apply existing procedures to iterate over our input and find the answer:

```
(define (only-multiples lst)
  (filter (lambda (num)
            (ormap (curry is-multiple? num) lst))
          lst))
```

It works as expected:

```
(only-multiples '(2 4 5 7 10))
=> '(4 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#lang racket
(require math)

(define numbers '(2 4 5 7 10))

(define (count-divisors-in-numbers n)
  ; count how many numbers d in the list numbers, are a divisor of n.
  (for/sum ([d numbers] #:when (divides? d n)) 1))

(define (multiple-of-other? n)
  ; Note: a number is always a multiplum of it self,
  ;       so only if the count is greater than 1,
  ;       the number is a multiplum of another number
  (> (count-divisors-in-numbers n) 1))

(filter multiple-of-other? numbers)
```

The result is `'(4 10)`.